# List index out of range error for index within the range of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am attempting to index a list to pull the first (0) and second (1) items for further calculations. My code currently looks like this:

```
def calculate_scores(list):
    sat = list[0]
    gpa = list[1]
    weighted_sat = (sat / 160)
    weighted_gpa = (gpa * 2)
```

This is in the function that I want to use to do the calculations. The part where this function is called in my main looks like this:

```
testscores = []
semestergrades = []

testscores.append(floatlist[0:4])
semestergrades.append(floatlist[4:])

calculate_scores(testscores)
```

The list that the testscores list is pulling from is 8 items long, all of them floats - however, when I try to run this code it gives me a 'list index out of range' error for the part where I try to set the variable 'gpa' equal to list[1]. However, it seems to be able to run the first part, setting the variable 'sat' equal to list[0]. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that all of the lists are the same length? Try some debugging, maybe print the value of `list` before you set gpa, or set a breakpoint and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.append()` when you should either be using `.extend()` or just using the result of the slice:

```
# floatlist = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
testscores = []
testscores.append(floatlist[0:4])
# testscores = [[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]]
```

So, how you're currently doing it, `testscores` is a list with one element, that element being `floatlist[0:4]`. When you try to use the second element (index `1`), you get an IndexError.

You can use `.extend()` instead of `.append()` to add all the items in the given iterable to the list. Or, you could just do

```
testscores = floatlist[0:4]
```

since list slicing produces a copy of the original anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Saved my homework grade, or at least this part of it!